# is it possible that SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed AND SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased are 'called'?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there a use case where first `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is called with `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` and at a later time with `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`?

I thought I saw such a behavior when the user enters a wrong password (`Failed`) and then the correct one (`Purchased`), but it doesn't seem to be the case.

I've got crashes with my app which I can only explain with the flow that first it fails and then succeeds. Does anyone know if that's a possible use case?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (when the user is asked to update their CC info, agree to new terms, or something else), there's a possibility of getting SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed before getting SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased. So, one should not treat SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed as a definitely permanent failure.